# How to locate the Unexpected token < in cordova command?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

The cordova command: **cordova platform update ios**.

The I got this **Syntax Error: Unexpected token <**

```
Updating ios project...
iOS project updated with cordova-ios@3.9.2
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.PlatformJson.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/PlatformJson.js:35:21)
    at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:49:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:110:28
    at Array.map (native)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:74:40
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
```

The error message is clear enough. But the problem is that all the details listed point to js libraries instead of something in my code. Where in my code should I look into to locate this extra `<`? Does an error in `PlatformJson.load` tell me something?

---

Update

I just found out there is something in `plugins\ios.json`.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
                        "xml": "<feature name=\"SplashScreen\"><param name=\"ios-package\" value=\"CDVSplashScreen\" /><param name=\"onload\" value=\"true\" /></feature>",
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
=======
>>>>>>> 47d85e461bd2df52351970ef12c1423411e9178f
```

Anyone knows where does this `<<< HEAD` come from? What is it for?

Comment: it happens when there is conflicts during GIT pull and merge..

Comment: Yep. Mohammed is very close. You need to do another download. FWIW: if you are using the command line interface CLI, your are not using *Phonegap Build*.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed what went wrong.